# Error when trying to add specific UserControls in the Form's Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

At some point in the development of this private project, some UserControls disappeared from the designer. They were still visible when executing the project, since they are declared, initialized and added to the window in the `Form1.Designer.cs` file.
I first ignored this problem, since I thought it was just a visual bug or something similar. Later in the development process, I had to visually design something around these UserControls, which forced me to fix the problem with this problem.
When trying to add a new instance of the UserControl `PartUC`, I received a similar if not the same error as below (just a really long error message). This error message occurred when trying to add the UserControl `PartUC` as well as completely new UserControls. Adding a new `AmpPropertiesUC` or `PartPropertiesUC` UserControl **is no problem** at all (this is what confuses me the most, it's not that every UserControl works except for one or two (as you would probably expect). It's exactly the other way around. **None** of the UserControls work except for two)

After not really finding a solution to solve this problem, I decided to redesign the Window in a completely new project. I used the `Form1.Designer.cs` file as a reference for the names, locations, sizes, colors, etcetera to speed up the process.
After I was done redesigning the main window and the `PartUC` UserControl, I added the `AmpPropertiesUC` and the `PartPropertiesUC` UserControl to the Project's directory and built the project, so they appear in the Toolbox.

Now, I added the `AmpPropertiesUC` and the `PartPropertiesUC` UserControls to the Form in the designer. After adding these, I tried to add the newly recreated `PartUC` to the newly recreated Form, but I still can't add the UserControl, even though I redesigned the window as well as the UserControl using the .Designer.cs file as a reference.
I **am** now able to add new, empty UserControls, but I still can't add the `PartUC` UserControl.

At this point, I'm just completely out of ideas of what could be the cause of this problem, since I also can't think of anything in the souce code, which could cause this error.

Here's a screenshot of the error message:

[image: Error Message occurring, when trying to add the UserControl PartUC]

and here's a screenshot of what the Form (from the old project) looks like with the `PartUC` UserControls (red) as well as a `PartUC` with some properties changed (blue) in the properties tab (green), which is a `PartPropertiesUC` UserControl:

[image]

Here's the source code for the `PartUC` UserControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ActiveFilterSimulator
{
    public delegate void PartUCEventHandler(PartUC sender);

    public partial class PartUC : UserControl
    {
        public event PartUCEventHandler PartClicked;

        private string _partName { set; get; }
        public string PartName
        {
            set
            {
                _partName = value;
                if ((_partType == "Open") || (_partType == "Connection"))
                    lName.Text = "";
                else
                    lName.Text = _partName;
            }
            get
            {
                return _partName;
            }
        }

        private double _partValue { set; get; }
        public double PartValue
        {
            set
            {
                _partValue = value;
                ScientifficValue scientifficValue = ScientifficValue.ParseValueToScientifficValue(value);

                if ((PartType == "Open") || (PartType == "Connection"))
                    lValue.Text = "";
                else
                    lValue.Text = scientifficValue.BareValue.ToString() + GetExtension(_partType, scientifficValue.ValueScientiffic);
            }
            get
            {
                return _partValue;
            }
        }

        private string _partType { set; get; }
        public string PartType
        {
            set
            {
                _partType = value;
                switch (_partType)
                {
                    case "Connection":
                        PartSymbolPannel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(getPrivateImageFolder() + "Connection.png");
                        break;
                    case "Resistor":
                        PartSymbolPannel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(getPrivateImageFolder() + "Resistor.png");
                        break;
                    case "Capacitor":
                        PartSymbolPannel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(getPrivateImageFolder() + "Capacitor.png");
                        break;
                    case "Inductor":
                        PartSymbolPannel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(getPrivateImageFolder() + "Inductor.png");
                        break;
                    default:
                        //Open Connection / Not Connected
                        _partType = "Open";
                        PartSymbolPannel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(getPrivateImageFolder() + "Open.png");
                        break;
                }

                PartName = _partName;
                PartValue = _partValue;
            }
            get
            {
                return _partType;
            }
        }

        public PartUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PartName = "";
            PartValue = 1.0f;
            PartType = "Open";
        }

        private void InvokeClickedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PartUCEventHandler handler = PartClicked;
            handler?.Invoke(this);
        }

        private string getPrivateImageFolder()
        {
            string CurrentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            CurrentDir = CurrentDir.Replace(@"bin\Debug\net6.0-windows", @"PartSymbols\");
            return CurrentDir;
        }

        private string GetExtension(string type, int scientiffic)
        {
            string scientifficCharacter;

            switch (scientiffic)
            {
                case 18:
                    scientifficCharacter = "E"; //Exa
                    break;
                case 15:
                    scientifficCharacter = "P"; //Peta
                    break;
                case 12:
                    scientifficCharacter = "T"; //Tera
                    break;
                case 9:
                    scientifficCharacter = "G"; //Giga
                    break;
                case 6:
                    scientifficCharacter = "M"; //Mega
                    break;
                case 3:
                    scientifficCharacter = "k"; //kilo
                    break;
                case 0:
                    scientifficCharacter = ""; //1
                    break;
                case -3:
                    scientifficCharacter = "m"; //milli
                    break;
                case -6:
                    scientifficCharacter = "µ"; //micro
                    break;
                case -9:
                    scientifficCharacter = "n"; //nano
                    break;
                case -12:
                    scientifficCharacter = "p"; //pico
                    break;
                case -15:
                    scientifficCharacter = "f"; //femto
                    break;
                case -18:
                    scientifficCharacter = "a"; //atto
                    break;
                default:
                    scientifficCharacter = "*"; //Unit prefix out of range
                    break;
            }

            switch (_partType)
            {
                case "Connection":
                    return "";
                case "Resistor":
                    return scientifficCharacter + "Ω";
                case "Capacitor":
                    return scientifficCharacter + "F";
                case "Inductor":
                    return scientifficCharacter + "H";
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the source code (generated by visual studio of course) from the designer file of the `PartUC` UserControl (`PartUC.Designer.cs`):

```
namespace ActiveFilterSimulator
{
    partial class PartUC
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.PartSymbolPannel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.lName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lValue = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // PartSymbolPannel
            // 
            this.PartSymbolPannel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.PartSymbolPannel.Name = "PartSymbolPannel";
            this.PartSymbolPannel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 75);
            this.PartSymbolPannel.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // lName
            // 
            this.lName.AutoSize = true;
            this.lName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Open Sans Light", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.lName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 5);
            this.lName.Name = "lName";
            this.lName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 23);
            this.lName.TabIndex = 1;
            this.lName.Text = "lName";
            // 
            // lValue
            // 
            this.lValue.AutoSize = true;
            this.lValue.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Open Sans Light", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.lValue.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 28);
            this.lValue.Name = "lValue";
            this.lValue.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 23);
            this.lValue.TabIndex = 2;
            this.lValue.Text = "lValue";
            // 
            // PartUC
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.lValue);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lName);
            this.Controls.Add(this.PartSymbolPannel);
            this.Name = "PartUC";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 75);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private Panel PartSymbolPannel;
        private Label lName;
        private Label lValue;
    }
}
```

Here's the link to the whole repository in case you need any other files:
https://github.com/HeCoding180/ActiveFilterSimulator

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Rewrite your `getPrivateImageFolder()`. Don't use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` or `Environment.GetCurrentDirectory()` or anything *Current*. If you want the executable path, that's `Application.StartupPath`. Also, use `Path.Combine()` to build paths. Always. -- Since you're there, you may want to add those images to the Project's Resources instead of loading from a file each time. Of course, you assign Resource objects to local Bitmaps, don't load from the Resources each time (`Project.Resources` is a Factory). Dispose on close.

Comment: The error is probably due to an event.  I would add a bunch of break points and see which ones you hit.  Put a break point in PartUC() on InitializeComponent() and line after which is the first two places code will reach.  Also at start of each event.  You may be hitting an event before the constructor is completed.

Comment: BTW, you can never refer to a folder that is contained in the directory structure of your Project. Those paths don't exist anymore when you deploy. If you want to add files and folders to the Project, then change the files' Build Action, so those files are copied to the build output directory (`bin\Debug` and `bin\Release`, if not modified).

Comment: do you build your project as first action after opening it?

Comment: @jdweng I don't think that this would do anything at all... The error occurrs when I'm dragging the user control into the windows form, hence I'm not actually debugging the code when the error occurrs, but you could actually be right with the event. Setting the part type loads a picture into a pannel on the user control. I should move the initialization code to the user control's load function. Thanks a lot, I'll try it out tomorrow

Comment: @Jimi yes, I know, It's really ugly but I just did a quick implementation for the images to try out the code and see how it looks because I might want to edit or completely change them.

Comment: It's not about aesthetics, that path is wrong, that's not the way to build a path (in any case), any *CurrentDirectory* will fail at some point, simply because it returns the *current* directory, not the *immutable* directory, hence what's *current* can be something completely different from what you expect (if, for undefined reasons, you expect it to be something specific). -- When an UC generates exception when dropped on a Form, it's because its bitness is not correct, because the Constructor throws or one of the Properties (accessible in the PropertyGrid or serialized) throws.

Comment: Also when you add, remove or change parts that are subject to serialization (in the Form Designer) and you don't remove the UC from all Forms that contain an instance before rebuilding the UC (which is mandatory).

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense but I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code then close your solution,Rebuild and try.
Add this line of code on load UC

```
 if (!this.DesignMode)
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }
```